# jquery Help - Expanded menu mobile not closing on my one page website menu selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In mobile view of my page, when the menu option is selected, it drops down and an expanded class value is added. That value never gets removed once I click on a menu element. I need to remove the expanded class value when any item in the menu is clicked and remove the expanded menu since it covers the entire page of my one page site.

[check in mobile view.](http://7drives.in/dsq/)

```
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="" style="position: fixed; top: 0px;"> 
  .
  .
  .
</nav>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        var clickover = $(event.target);
        var _opened = $(".expanded").hasClass("expanded in");
        if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
            $("button.navbar-toggle").click();
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

You can remove that "expanded" class from the "top-bar" for each menu item click by checking that class is exist.

```
$(".top-bar-section ul li > a").click(function() {
    if($('.top-bar').hasClass('expanded')){
        $('.top-bar').removeClass('expanded')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#menuContent').toggleClass('expanded')` when the menu button is clicked, and `$('#menuContent').removeClass('expanded')` when a menu item is clicked, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menuButton').click(function(event) {
        $('#menuContent').toggleClass('expanded');
    });

    $('.menuItem').click(function(event) {
        $('#menuContent').removeClass('expanded');
    });

});
```

[Here is a fully functional JSFiddle to demonstrate.](https://jsfiddle.net/ifinto/o2gxgz9r/)

Comment: HI the above code given by you is still not helping me out.

Comment: Also, the JSFiddle is not looking relevant to my issue mentioned here